# how to use multi variables in a single SQL python code

Tags: python, sql

I have used this code to use two variables in a single SQL code in Python :

```
cursor.execute("select * from customers WHERE username=%s and password=%s", (a, b))
```

but I've got this error :

> MySQLInterfaceError: Python type tuple cannot be converted

though I've converted my strings into a tuple like this:

```
a = tuple(map(str, emaile.split(",")))
b = tuple(map(str, passe.split(",")))
```

how can I use these two variables in my `cursor.execute` code?

Comment: Could you describe in a bit more detail what you are trying to do? From the `split()` stuff, it looks like you are dealing with comma-separated lists of addresses and passwords, but I see nothing dealing with lists in the SQL...

Comment: i prefer check this `https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/tutorial.html#executing`

Comment: Your problem is not the 2 variables, it is that the variables are themselves tuples.  Also, the notion of using passwords to query a db is… disturbing security-wise and probably pointless sql-wise if customer is keyed by username.  You probably need to use a loop.  or `username in (…)` which can be tricky with binds.  And doesnt work with another list for another var (that password)

Comment: @TurePålsson I'm trying to convert my strings to a tuple because its needed data format for cursor.execute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
query = """select * from customers WHERE username=%s and password=%s"""
tuple1 = ("mini", 9000)
cursor.execute(query, tuple1)
```

Comment: Try doing it in a cleaner way step by step, try it, if it doesn't print them and see. It will work :)

Answer (score 0):

cursor.execute("INSERT INTO table VALUES (%s, %s, %s)", (var1, var2, var3))

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/902408/how-to-use-variables-in-sql-statement-in-python

Comment: Sahil as you see my variables are not in  series  i need to have an "And" between them so how should i mention them after ","